# Creating a visible frame when using the Camera

Tags: flutter, android-camera

I've been searching unsuccessfully for a way to incorporate a frame to the camera when in use in the app.

can anyone assist providing an answer or a source on this?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Example for desired outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this package [camerax](https://pub.dev/packages/camerax), it allows us to position the camera view in the widget tree, thus allowing we to input it to stack and draw something on top of it.

there is example in the git repo of the project that show you how to do that.